# figure not put on the top of the page

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I would like the figure envirement to be put on the top of this page, but whatever I do it remains at the middle of the page...

here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=5mm,bottom=50mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tipa}


\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}


\addbibresource{reffence.bib}


\renewcommand\headrule{%
\vspace{-6pt}
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}









\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}}

\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[section]


\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Παράδειγμα~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}




\fancyhf{}

\setlength{\headheight}{95pt}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\textbf{\thepage}}

\pagestyle{fancy}



\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{logometitlo2.png}}


\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

And here the figure I cannot fix.....

```
\begin{figure}[pt]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{notglobalrigidspiti.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{notglobalrigidspiti}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{alexandrovrigidity.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{alexandrovrigiditysxima}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{}

 \end{figure}
```

[image: problematic figure...]

How can I put the figure on the top of the page?

Comment: unrelated but the option is `twoside`  the version `two side` that you have only works by an accident of the implementation (and may not work in classes using newer option handlers)

Comment: a figure can only use `t` if it is placed on a page with text you have provided no example but is there text that could be placed under the figure? (it is best to always provide a complete test document, you can use `example-image` as the image)  figures placed on float pages are vertically centred by default, although you could change that to top alignment (ser `\@fptop` to 0pt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\begin{figure}[ht!]`

[image: a]

This is a simplified code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=5mm,bottom=50mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}    

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}   

\renewcommand\headrule{%
    \vspace{-6pt}
    \hrulefill
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}
    {\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
    \hrulefill}

\newcommand{\arc}[1]{{%
        \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
        \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}}

\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[section]


\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
    \noindent \textbf{Παράδειγμα~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\fancyhf{}

\setlength{\headheight}{95pt}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\textbf{\thepage}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht!]% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \label{notglobalrigidspiti}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
            \label{alexandrovrigiditysxima}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{}
        
    \end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```